# Solve the inequality

Tags: inequality

$2\left|x+\frac{1}{4}\right| < 9$

I keep trying to figure this out and I can't.

I tried to split up the absolute value first.

$2 (x+\frac{1}{4}) < 9$

$2+x+\frac{1}{4} < 9$

subtract $2$ from both sides? $x+\frac{1}{4} < 7$

and

$2 -(x+\frac{1}{4}) < 9$

$2-x-\frac{1}{4} < 9$

subtract $2$ from both sides? $-x-\frac{1}{4} < 7$

well that's not right. I suck at this. :c

Thanks for any helpers.

Comment: Use these two facts: __FACT1:__ $k.|y| \leq A \implies |y| \leq \frac{A}{k}$ $\quad$ __FACT2:__ $|y| \leq B \implies -B \leq y \leq B$

Comment: How did you get from $2(x+\frac14)$ to $2+x+\frac14$? (You need to use the distributive property here.)

Answer (score 1):

We have $|x+1/4|<9/2$. Now read that out loud: “The distance from $x$ to $-1/4$ is less than $9/2$.”

Answer (score 0):

Write $2|\frac{x+1}{4}|<9$ as $\frac{-9}{2}<\frac{x+1}{4}<\frac{9}{2}.$ This gives $-18<x+1<18$ which is $-19<x<17$

Answer (score 0):

$2|x+0,25| < 9 \rightarrow |x+0,25| < 4,5 \rightarrow |x| < 4,25 \rightarrow -4,25 < x <4,25$

You can negate $0,25$ from each side, since it is positive, and the absolute value won't effect it.